# Floating elements around a previous element in markup

Tags: css, css-float

I've got some fairly basic markup for a header, an image, and some text ([example](http://dabblet.com/gist/1624758)):

```
<div>
  <h1>
  <img>
  <p>
</div>
```

**I'd like to float the image left of both the preceding header *and* the succeeding paragraph, without changing the HTML.**

Ideally, I'd simply float the image left:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

But because the header appears before the image in the markup, the header will span the entire container:

```
/-----------------------------------------\
| Header Header Header                    |
| |-------|                               |
| |-Image-|  Paragraph text               |
| |-------|  Paragraph text               |
| |-------|  Paragraph text               |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
/-----------------------------------------\
| |-------|  Header Header Header         |
| |-------|                               |
| |-Image-|  Paragraph text               |
| |-------|  Paragraph text               |
| |-------|  Paragraph text               |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

[**My efforts so far (Dabblet)**](http://dabblet.com/gist/1624758)

I can float the `<h1>` to the right, but the width of the image will vary, so I can't specify a constant width for the  element. I would prefer to keep the above markup order because it makes more sense semantically, and when the displayed unstyled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one possible way](http://jsfiddle.net/CPeSH/1/).

Markup:

```
<div>
    <h2>This is my title</h2>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320x200/ff00ff/fff&text=woooo!" alt="sample" />
    <p>I'd like to float the image left of both the preceding header and the succeeding paragraph, without changing the HTML. I'd like to float the image left of both the preceding header and the succeeding paragraph, without changing the HTML. I'd like to float the image left of both the preceding header and the succeeding paragraph, without changing the HTML. I'd like to float the image left of both the preceding header and the succeeding paragraph, without changing the HTML.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { position: relative; }
img { float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
p { position: relative; top: 24px; }
h2 { position: absolute; left: 340px; font-weight: bold; }
```

Visual example (in Firefox):

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but setting the left margin of the `<h2>` element to emulate the float will only work if the image has a fixed width ;_;

Comment: Yeah, this solution is problematic if the widths change, and if the `h2` breaks on to more than 1 line :/

Answer (score -1):

Here is so far my solution.

You can find it here : http://jsfiddle.net/gHNdJ/

Hope this is what you are searching for.

Note: if you still want to keep the html like that, the solution of the first answer is the best so far. but I'm not like using positioning.

Comment: If the `<img>` is before the `<h1>` in markup order--as it is in your solution--the CSS can be simply reduced to floating the `<img>` to the left. Your use of containing `<div>` elements is over-complicating the solution, which still unfortunately doesn't work when the `<h1>` occurs before the image ;_;